# Change font of the active section/subsection in the navigation

Tags: beamer, navigation

I would like to change the font of the (sub)sections in the navigation of a beamer document. But **only** for the current (sub)section. The headline of the frames currently looks like this:
[image]

I would like to make the active (sub)section bigger. I know about the command `\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\small}`, but this also changes the size of the inactive sections.

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.5840 under Windows 7 with TeXstudio.

**Example Document**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{palette secondary}
        \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{palette tertiary}
        \vskip2pt\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hfill}{\hfill}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{english}

    % Title Page
    {\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=white,bg=white}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}}

    % Content
    \section{Section 1}

    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \section{Section 2}

    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \section{Section 3}

    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \section{Section 4}

    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
\end{document}
```

---

**Why I want to do this?**

I want to give an overview of the progress of the presentation, while emphasizing the current position. This allows me to get rid of the (in my opinion) space wasting and redundant frame titles.

Comment: Running your example I get white sections. I'm using Texlive 2015,  beamer.cls    2015/01/05 3.36

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I totally forgot that I set the linkcolor to black via `\hypersetup`. I changed the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `section in head/foot shaded` inherits its appearance from `section in head/foot`, but when redefining it, one could sneak in extra command, like the `\tiny` in the following example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Rochester}
\usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{palette secondary}
        \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{palette tertiary}
        \vskip2pt\insertsubsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hfill}{\hfill}\vskip2pt
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\small}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}
{\color{fg!50!bg}\tiny\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}

\begin{document}

    % Title Page
    {\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=white,bg=white}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}}

    % Content
    \section{Section 1}

    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \section{Section 2}

    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \section{Section 3}

    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \section{Section 4}

    \subsection{Subsection 1}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 2}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}

    \subsection{Subsection 3}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
    \frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image]