# beamer warsaw modify heading color (roght side) in relation to sections

Tags: beamer, sectioning, color

I'm using the Warsaw template for beamer class. I would like that the color of the left heading of my presentation vary by section (each section has a customised color.
I saw a solution here: [Changing color in beamer header (Singapore)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53288/changing-color-in-beamer-header-singapore) 
However, this is adapted to Singapore theme and is very customised. 
Is there any help, please.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `section in head/foot color` from section to section:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=blue!50!black}
\section{sec1}
\subsection{sub1}   
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=red!50!black}
\section{sec2}
\subsection{sub2}   
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

You can even make the colour change automatic:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\definecolorseries{foo}{rgb}{last}{red}{blue}
\resetcolorseries[3]{foo}

\AtBeginSection[]{%
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{bg=foo!![\thesection]}
}

\begin{document}

\section{sec1}
\subsection{sub1}   
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{sec2}
\subsection{sub2}   
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\section{sec3}
\subsection{sub3}   
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer, however, I want to modify the right part color, not the left one. So, each subsection group has the same color. Thank you again

Comment: @BeyRout Upps! Please see my edited answer.

Comment: A last question please, how can I customise the color series to pick exactly some defined colors!

Comment: and I saw that you gave once a solution to change section subsection font size for the active slide. But, I don't figure out how to adapt it to my case. Can you please help me to do it. Thank you very much

Comment: @BeyRout Colour series only interpolate between the first and the last colour. If you want other colours, do it manually like in my first solution.

Comment: Can you give me a link?

Comment: Here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305373/change-font-of-the-active-section-subsection-in-the-navigation I am sorry, I am customising my template and I am newer to latex so I struggle to find the syntax. In addition please, how we change also the content table section colors like the customized color of the heading.

Comment: @BeyRout Both of your new questions require some code to answer them. It would be better if you asked two new questions.