How to change fancy chapter style for each chapter?
I want to colour each chapter with a different color. I'm new to latex so I hope I'm providing enough information. I'm using the fancy "Bjornstrup" style, and I want to change the colour of the box every chapter, so each chapter can be identified with that colour.
Here is my .tex.
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4} % Interlineado

\usepackage{geometry} % Margin and layout
\geometry{
 includefoot,
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=27mm,
 top=40mm,
 headsep=10mm,
 right=27mm,
 bottom=27mm,
 footskip=15mm
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Headers and footers
\usepackage{lastpage} % To reference last page's number
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\colortitlechap}{\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}} % color of the chapter title <<<
\newcommand{\colornumberchap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter number <<<<
\newcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox[rgb]{.129,0.1,0.82}} % color of the background rules <<<

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}% 
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\colornumberchap\CNoV\thechapter}\\%
}

\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@%
}

\renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}\\%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@%
}

\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor,lipsum}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% Define margin colors
\definecolor{marginColor1}{HTML}{FBE8E8}
\definecolor{marginColor2}{HTML}{E8FBE8}
\definecolor{marginColor3}{HTML}{E8E8FB}
% Add more colors as needed

% Custom margin square command
\newcommand{\marginsquare}[1]{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \AtPageUpperRight{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
                \fill[#1] ($(current page.north east)+(0,-3cm)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east)+(-1.5cm,-4.5cm)$);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
}

% Set up fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{Página \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3mm}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0mm}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Capítulo}

% Apply the margin square to every page
\newcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor1}}}

% Initially apply the first color
%\applymarginsquare

\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello}
% Change the margin square color for the next chapter
\renewcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor1}}}
\applymarginsquare
\section{Some dummy text}
\blindtext[10]

\changechaptercolor{0.3,0.3,0.3}
\chapter{World}
% Change the margin square color for the next chapter
\renewcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor2}}}
\applymarginsquare
\section{Another dummy text}
\blindtext[10]

\chapter{Example}
% Change the margin square color for the next chapter
\renewcommand{\applymarginsquare}{\AddEverypageHook{\marginsquare{marginColor3}}}
\applymarginsquare
\section{Yet another dummy text}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}


Thanks in advanced, I have tried How do I change the color of the background on my chapter style in fncychap? (\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}) and it works but don't know how to make it changeable for each chapter.

You could use a colour series instead of an hard coded colour for your chapter style, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402963/36296

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz updated the code, although it has errors of some package, it runs propperly. Thanks.

Please never ever ignore error messages! Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Please also make a test file which does not require puzzling together multiple code fragments.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sorry for that, I don't know why errors appear as they're in a package file. Updated  the code again :(. Thaks for your patience.

If you have errors in your code, you should better ask a question about how to fix them instead of worrying about the colours of your chapters.

You could manually change the colour before each chapter:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\colortitlechap}{\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}} % color of the chapter title <<<
\newcommand{\colornumberchap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter number <<<<
\newcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox[rgb]{.129,0.1,0.82}} % color of the background rules <<<

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}% 
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\colornumberchap\CNoV\thechapter}\\%
}

\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@%
}


\makeatother


\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{red}} 
\chapter{Example}

\renewcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{blue}} 
\chapter{Example}

\renewcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{green}} 
\chapter{Example}

\renewcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{yellow}} 
\chapter{Example}

\end{document}



Or you could use the same approach as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402963/36296 and use a colour series to change colours automatically:
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolorseries{foo}{rgb}{last}{red}{blue}
\resetcolorseries[5]{foo}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\colortitlechap}{\color[rgb]{0.9,0.9,0.9}} % color of the chapter title <<<
\newcommand{\colornumberchap}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} % color of the chapter number <<<<
\newcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{foo!![\thechapter]}} % color of the background rules <<<

\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\DOCH}{%
    \settowidth{\py}{\CNoV\thechapter}
    \addtolength{\py}{-10pt}% 
    \fboxsep=0pt%
    \colorbackchap{\rule{0pt}{40pt}\parbox[b]{\textwidth}{\hfill}}%
    \kern-\py\raise20pt%
    \hbox{\colornumberchap\CNoV\thechapter}\\%
}

\renewcommand{\DOTI}[1]{%
    \nointerlineskip\raggedright%
    \fboxsep=\myhi%
    \vskip-1ex%
    \colorbackchap{\parbox[t]{\mylen}{\CTV\FmTi{\colortitlechap#1}}}\par\nobreak%
    \vskip 40\p@%
}




\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Example}

\chapter{Example}

\chapter{Example}

\chapter{Example}

\end{document}



\renewcommand{\colorbackchap}{\colorbox{marginColor2}} % color of the background rules <<< before each \chapter{}
